# Deleting all items of a ttk.Treeview does not delete or unconfigure their tagNames?

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview, tcl

I noticed a strange phenomenon in the `ttk.Treeview`. Below is my test code to demonstrate the phenomenon.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class App(ttk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.top_iids = []
        self.child_iids = []
        self._create_widget()
        
    def _create_widget(self):
        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(
            self, height=10, selectmode='extended', takefocus=True,)
        self.tree.column('#0', stretch=True, width=200, anchor='w')
        self.tree.heading('#0', text="Col0", anchor='w')
        self.bn1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Populate", command=self.populate)        
        self.bn2 = ttk.Button(self, text="TagConfigure", command=self.tagconfig)
        self.bn3 = ttk.Button(self, text="Reset", command=self.reset)

        self.tree.grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=4, padx=5, pady=5)
        self.bn1.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)
        self.bn2.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)
        self.bn3.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)

    def populate(self):
        counter = 0
        for i in range(4):
            self.tree.tag_configure(i)
            tliid = f"G{i}"
            self.tree.insert("", "end", iid=tliid, open=True,
                             tags=[tliid], text=f"Restaurant {i}")
            ciid = f"F{counter}"
            self.tree.insert(tliid, "end", iid=ciid, text=f"Cookie", 
                             tags=[ciid], values=(ciid))
            self.top_iids.append(tliid)
            self.child_iids.append(ciid)
            counter+=1
            
    def tagconfig(self):
        self.tree.tag_configure('F2', foreground='red')
        self.tree.tag_configure('F3', foreground='red')

    def reset(self):
        print(f"def reset(self):")
        top_level_nodes = self.tree.get_children()
        self.tree.delete(*top_level_nodes)
        tln_exist = {i:self.tree.exists(i) for i in top_level_nodes}
        chn_exist = {i:self.tree.exists(i) for i in self.child_iids}
        print(f"{tln_exist=}")
        print(f"{chn_exist=}")
        
        # uncomment to make iids F2 & F3 black at 2nd press of Populate button
        # self.tree.tag_configure('F2', foreground='')
        # self.tree.tag_configure('F3', foreground='') 


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = App(root)
    app.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

When the buttons are pressed in the following sequence, <kbd>Populate</kbd>--><kbd>TagConfigure</kbd>--><kbd>Reset</kbd>--><kbd>Populate</kbd>, items `F2` and `F3` continue to be in red color after they have been destroyed.

[image: Treeview_issue]

Also, see printed-out messages after Reset Button is pressed, which confirms all treeview items have been destroyed, i.e. become non-existent:

```
def reset(self):
tln_exist={'G0': False, 'G1': False, 'G2': False, 'G3': False}
chn_exist={'F0': False, 'F1': False, 'F2': False, 'F3': False}
```

To fix this issue, I have to issue the following commands in the `self.reset()` method:

```
self.tree.tag_configure('F2', foreground='')
self.tree.tag_configure('F3', foreground='')
```

According to documentation, the 1st argument of `ttk.Treeview.tag_configure(tagName, option=None, **kw)` is a `tagName`. Consequently, it means that tagName `F2` & `F3` still exist despite all items in the Treeview widget had been destroyed.

Simply put, tagNames are undestroyed even though all treeview items have been destroyed via `self.tree.delete(*self.tree.get_children())`. Is this understanding correct? If so, is there an equivalent command to the `ttk.Treeview.delete(*items)` method where one can undo and/or destroy all old tagNames and their configurations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Simply put, tagNames are undestroyed even though all treeview items have been destroyed via self.tree.delete(*self.tree.get_children()). Is this understanding correct?

Yes, that's correct.

> If so, is there an equivalent command to the `ttk.Treeview.delete(*items)` method where one can undo and/or  destroy all old tagNames and their configurations?

There is no way to delete a tag, which seems to me like an oversight in the design of the treeview widget. You can specify the options as empty strings to reset them.

Oddlly, tkinter doesn't expose the `tag names` command, but you can easily call it to get a list of all tag names. And with that, you can reset all of the options of that tag to an empty string.

Here's an example of a function that should reset the tag options:

```
def reset_tags(self):
    for tag_name in self.tk.call(self.tree, "tag", "names"):
        self.tree.tag_configure(tag_name, foreground="", background="", font="", image="")
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on <You can specify the options as empty strings to reset them.>? I don't understand. Example?

Comment: This will be fixed in Tk 8.7: https://core.tcl-lang.org/tips/doc/trunk/tip/574.md